# scala lift comet

Tags: scala, lift

So basically I need a system like this:

- We got users
- Users have friends

Now the users if they come on the website they can post an "activity" just like twitter, they type in what they are doing, and all their friends get with a realtime update.

I have looked at lift for a week or three, and I digged into the chat server example, how ever as I said how can I make an comet actor for "activities" that where posted by friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two general approachs:

1. Do it the same way like the chat example: Just use one "Chat"server that holds all activities and every user is registred with. If a new activity is posted, every user would be informed and has to check if the activity was posted by one if its friends (via match/PartialFunction probably). If yes it display it, otherwise discard it.
2. Use one "Chat"server per user and register only the user's friends with this server. Note: I don't know if you need one comet listener per server for each of the user you are following in this case or if a comet listener can listen to several servers. If you need one listener per server, you will have to combine all activities you're listening to before displaying theese.

Approach 1 is closer to the ChatServer example but I would suggest to follow approach 2 since there's less communication in it so it should scale better. Also using different servers should improve scalability since you're able to do partitioning based on that. Of course you will have to some more management than using only one singleton "Chat"server.